# Sending and recieving text data from dialogueflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

How can I intergrate dialogueflow with my chat interface?
I want to send and recieve text data from dialogueflow instead of using iframe or dialogueflow messenger.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following details below to integrate Dialogflow with your own web chat interface:

For **Dialogflow CX**:

- [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.sessions/detectIntent) method - used to send user queries to your agent.
- [detectIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/DetectIntentResponse) - the response from your agent. You can then process this data to display messages in your chat interface.
- [Interaction with the API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api)
- [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/overview)
- [Rest API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3-overview)
- [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc?hl=en)

For **Dialogflow ES**:

- [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.agent.sessions/detectIntent) method - used to send user queries to your agent
- [detectIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/DetectIntentResponse) - the response from your agent. You can then process this data to display messages in your chat interface.
- [Interaction with the API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api)
- [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/libraries/overview)
- [Rest API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview)
- [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2)

Comment: I need billing for using methods, right? Is there any way I can do this without billing? It's just for a personal project. If you can suggest any alternative of google dialogflow with simpler integration method, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

from the docs: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick

1. Set up your CX agent
2. Build the agent in the CX Agent Console
3. Use interactions & end-points to interact with an API.

Your chat interface can use the API.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my previous response, to answer the questions of Ashutosh Gupta:

The Billing in Dialogflow will depend on the edition of your agent.

- For **Dialogflow Trial** [edition](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/editions), billing is not required but there are limits on the amount of requests that you can make. This edition is suitable to experiment with Dialogflow.
- For **Dialogflow Essential** edition, billing is required for making calls to API requests.
- For **Dialogflow CX** edition, billing is required when enabling the API. However, each new customer will receive a $600 credit for a free trial of Dialogflow CX.

You can check the following documentation for more details:

- [Dialogflow Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/pricing)
- [Cloud Billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs)

In addition, there are some generic quotas and limits to ensure appropriate use of the platform. Please be noted that ​​Dialogflow quotas vary depending on the edition of your agent.  If you are using a paid edition, you can request a quota increase. Please check default limits and instructions to increase quotas from [Quotas and Limits documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas).

With this, you can try utilizing the Dialogflow Trial edition or try the $600 credit free trial of Dialogflow CX.

In addition, you can also check out the [Dialogflow Trial Edition Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/terms-trial-edition).